# Convergence of a stopped martingale to martingale at stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, probability-limit-theorems

For $S$ and stopping time and $M_n$ a martingale on $\mathbb{N}$ with respect to the same filtration, does it always hold that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} M_{S \wedge n} = M_S,$$
or do we need some extra conditions like convergence of $M_n$ or boundedness of $S$?

I thought that if $M_n$ has an a.s. limit $M_\infty$, we can argue that 
$$M_{S \wedge n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \mathbf{1}_{\{S=i\}} M_i + \mathbf{1}_{\{ S \geq n \}} M_n$$ and that this converges a.s. to $$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{S=i\}} M_i + \mathbf{1}_{\{ S = \infty \}} M_\infty = M_S.$$
Is this correct?

I am not sure how we would even define $M_S$ when $M_n$ does not have a limit and $S$ might be infinite.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathbb{P}(S<\infty)=1$ or if $M_\infty$ is defined almost everywhere then obviously $M_{S\wedge n}\to M_S$ almost surely. But if at some point $M_n$ does not converge and $S=\infty$ then at this point $M_{S\wedge n}=M_n$ for all $n$ and this sequence does not converge. So at such points $M_S$ is not really defined. So the problem is when the set of such points has positive probability. Then there is no almost sure convergence of $M_{S\wedge n}$.

Comment: When you say obviously, do you mean that the justification I gave is unnecessary? Could you explain why it is obvious in that case?

Comment: If at some point $S<\infty$ then at this point the sequence $M_{S\wedge n}$ eventually becomes the constant sequence $M_S$, hence it converges. Now, assume at some point $S=\infty$ and $M_n\to M_\infty$. The sequence $M_{S\wedge n}$ is just the sequence $M_n$ in that case and by our assumption it converges to $M_\infty$. (which is exactly $M_S$ since $S=\infty$).

Comment: Isn't that argument exactly what I have written with indicators, just in words?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is. And the main point is that when $S=\infty$ and $M_n$ does not converge we get that the sequence $M_{S\wedge n}$ doesn't converge. So if that happens on a set with positive probability then we can't say that $M_{S\wedge n}$ converges to $M_S$ almost surely. (which was your original question)